# How to get the folder which we hide from the side bar in sublime text?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I did not want a folder to be in when I search so I go to settings and added a command "folder_exclude_patterns": ["folder name"]

but it just disappeared from side bar so what should I do to get it back?

I removed that command still I did not get it back.

```
"folder_exclude_patterns": ["node_modules"]
"folder_exclude_patterns": [".next"]
```

Anyone?

Comment: Did you try restarting Sublime?

Comment: I just did reopen it and now when I am opening my folder , only a blank screen is visible to me and on the top it is written sublime(unregistered) and folder name